# configuring a seating arrangement in python

Tags: python, spyder

I want to create a random seating arrangement where I have 40 seats and 8 people. I approached the question as follows however I am unsure how to use 'random' or 'numpy' to generate a random seating arrangement without it replacing one of the already assigned seats.

```
seats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]

def seating_arrangement():
        random.choice(seats) = 1
```

Also I want to know how I can programme it to return a True or False statement if two people are seated together.

I am a beginner so your help would be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: can you give an example output as well

Answer (score 0):

To create such an arrangement:

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()
seats_taken = rng.choice(40, size=8)
seats = np.zeros(40)
for seat_taken in seats_taken:
    seats[seat_taken] = 1

seats
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
#        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
#        1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Then iterate to find if `seats` contains two consecutive ones

```
flag = False
for s in range(len(seats)-1):
    if seats[s] == seats[s+1] == 1:
        flag = True
```